# Tensorflow not executing correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, spyder

I am trying to run a sample tensorflow script: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py

When I run it the first time, I get an error at the end of the run:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

runfile('/Users/max/Desktop/mnist_with_summaries.py', wdir='/Users/max/Desktop')
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Accuracy at step 0: 0.141
Accuracy at step 10: 0.6992
Accuracy at step 20: 0.8042
Accuracy at step 30: 0.8514
Accuracy at step 40: 0.8786
Accuracy at step 50: 0.8867
Accuracy at step 60: 0.8941
Accuracy at step 70: 0.8891
Accuracy at step 80: 0.8925
Accuracy at step 90: 0.8983
Adding run metadata for 99
/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2889: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
```

Any subsequent run would break right after loading the data:

```
runfile('/Users/max/Desktop/mnist_with_summaries.py', wdir='/Users/max/Desktop')
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-c176905abc5f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/max/Desktop/mnist_with_summaries.py', wdir='/Users/max/Desktop')

  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/Users/max/Desktop/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 204, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)

  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))

  File "/Users/max/Desktop/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 185, in main
    train()

  File "/Users/max/Desktop/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 160, in train
    summary, acc = sess.run([merged, accuracy], feed_dict=feed_dict(False))

  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)

  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)

  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)

InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input/x-input' with dtype float
     [[Node: input/x-input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op u'input/x-input', defined at:
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/ipython/start_kernel.py", line 227, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/ipython/start_kernel.py", line 223, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 474, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 887, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 276, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 228, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 390, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 501, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-c176905abc5f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/max/Desktop/mnist_with_summaries.py', wdir='/Users/max/Desktop')
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 94, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/Users/max/Desktop/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 204, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/Users/max/Desktop/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 185, in main
    train()
  File "/Users/max/Desktop/mnist_with_summaries.py", line 48, in train
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='x-input')
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1587, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2043, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/Users/max/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input/x-input' with dtype float
     [[Node: input/x-input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

The only change I have done is to reduce the number of loops from 1000 to 100 in line 193 of the code (but the error occurs in any case).
I use Sypder and Python 2 on a Mac.

Any ideas how to fix this? Might there be anything wrong with the installation.

Also the code should write summaries for using with tensorboard. Where are these files stored? Can't find them in the location of the module (Desktop).

Thanks al lot for the help!

Comment: The files for Tensorboard should be in logdir should be `/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/logs/mnist_with_summaries` by default, and you can specify it with the command line option `--logdir`, see [line 201](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py#L201)